# mediaPlayer.release() causes onPause() to timeout - Motorola Xoom Family Edition

Tags: android

I'm running into a strange problem that only occurs on the Motorola Xoom Family Edition, and not on ten other testing devices--not even the Motorola Xoom Wi-Fi Edition.

After much frustrating experimentation, this seems to be what happens: if I prepare a MediaPlayer, using a file that isn't very small, and then attempt to release the player in onPause WITHOUT having ever called mediaPlayer.start(), then release() hangs onPause (I get a LogCat message saying onPause timed out) and the screen goes black. I have to press Home, go to Manage Application and force the app to stop because otherwise it will just be a permanent, unresponding black screen without the "Application Not Responding" dialog ever appearing.

Why does this happen? How can I prevent this issue from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an ugly hack, so I hope someone has a better answer, but this is my workaround.

I set a flag whenever I play the recording. Then in onPause I run:

```
if (!everPlayed) {
mediaPlayer.start();
mediaPlayer.release();
}
```